# how to merge these 2 arrays (php+sql)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays, both from a SQL query, each from a different database. Since it's not possible to merge these 2 SQL queries into 1 query to get 1 array (due to some restrictions), I am forced to combine the 2 arrays. Problem is, I can't seem to get this working.

This is array 1:

```
echo '<ul id="friends">';
    foreach($result as $friend => $value)
        {
            echo '<li><img src="'.$value['pic_square'].'" alt="" />'.$value['uid'].' ' . $value['name'] . '</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';
```

And will output:

- picture 12345 Dave
- picture 67890 Mike
- Etc

This is array 2:

```
echo '<ul id="friends">';
    while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        echo '<li> '.$value['fbid'] .' '. $value['userphone'] .'</li>';

        }
    echo '</ul>';
```

And will output:

- 12345 020-12345
- 67890 020-56789
- Etc

What do I need? I want to merge these 2 arrays so that the phonenr from array 2 will be added behind the username from array 1.

Example what the output should look like:

- picture Dave 020-12345
- picture Mike 020-56789
- Etc

fbid and uid are the id's to link each other, but are not shown in the combined array.

Hope someone knows how to do this!

Kind regards,

Maurice

Comment: Is there data coming from 2 different SQL servers? If not, is there any reason why you're not just joining the 2 tables together?

Comment: Yes they are coming from 2 different sql servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest and most efficient way I could think of doing it. The foreach loop iterates through your first array and basically add new key/value pairs using the "uid" as the key. This will enable you to easily find them when you loop through the second query's results.

```
<?php

// First query.
foreach ( $result as $key => $value )
{
  // Add a new key/value pair in the array using the "uid" as the key and $value as the value.
  $result[$value['uid']] = $value;

  // Remove the previous key/value pair value.
  unset($result[$key]);
}

// Second query.
while ( $value = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
  echo sprintf('<li>%s %s %s</li>', $result[$value['fbid']]['pic_square'], $result[$value['fbid']]['name'], $value['userphone']);
```

Answer (score -1):

As the array collection names are different (different column name) I am not sure direct merging will work.

```
$result = array_merge($result, $query);
print_r($result);
```

But you can work around like below.

Give loops and store in a third array from both the arrays and do necessary actions on third array.

Comment: Thanks but this gives me an error:

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /..../etc.

Apparently the while loop is not an array :( How to fix this? Thanks